# ProgressBar для ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

Прочитал https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/%D0%A1_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C и задумался как реализовать прогрессбар для процесса отправки и получения `httpRequest`, но как-то не додумался. Подскажите как мне это сделать.

Comment: возьми что-нибудь готовое, например https://github.com/HubSpot/pace

Comment: слушайте событие onprogress, в event будет сколько байт загружено и сколько всего